# Regex copy-paste line and add number with increment to the end of each

Tags: mysql, regex, notepad++

I need to create tones of Mysql queries such as

```
delete * from `post` WHERE  `postid` =5380;
```

and the last would be `282164`

I will use regex in `notepad++` to work it out.

I need help to create regex which would copy first line

```
delete * from `post` WHERE  `postid` =5380;
```

and paste it with increment +1 to the number `5380` till it reaches `282164`

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not:

```
DELETE FROM post WHERE postid BETWEEN 5380 AND 282164
```

Comment: because my server is dying after one such query

Comment: @user1991959: Then looping over 277,000 such queries is sure to finish it off.  Perhaps you need to build an index on `postid`?

Comment: it will be simple fast short queries, server should be ok with it

Comment: @user1991959: I *guarantee* you that the load on the server will be much greater when executing 277,000 `DELETE` statements versus a single statement that deletes 277,000 records.

Comment: at the end i tuned DB so its handled the query :) , thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off using Excel or generating a dynamic query inside of MySQL.

For example, in Excel you can put something like:

A1:
=CONCATENATE("delete * from post WHERE postid=", B1)

B1:
5380

And then repeat until 282164

... Or what eggyal said :)

Comment: "And then repeat until 282164" 
thats kinda problem :)))))

Answer (score 1):

What about a single query:

```
DELETE * FROM post WHERE postid BETWEEN 5380 AND 282164
```